# Is there a way to delete an ephemeral node after a client is disconnected by some time?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Our cluster nodes take actions on the deletion of some ephemeral nodes but we're having network issues at a customer that leads to the deletion of the ephemeral nodes for some clients, although those clients are still up and running.

I agree that the network issues should be solved but it doesn't look like we can do that at the moment.

So is there a way to configure Zookeeper to delete the ephemeral node for a disconnected client only if it stays disconnected for **X** amount of time ?

We use Apache Curator as a Zookeeper client.
Our Zookeeper version is 3.4.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play around with zookeeper's session timeout configuration to achieve the desired behavior. Zookeeper server will delete the ephemeral node for a session after not receiving any heartbeat from the client for the session timeout duration.

Comment: I'm having the defaul values (2000ms tickTime, iniLimit = 10 and syncLimit = 5) and the ephemeral node is gone once the client is disconnected. The client gets connected again in around 1 sec

Comment: Zookeeper server exposes minSessionTimeout and maxSessionTimeout configurations (in milliseconds) in zoo.cfg. During session establishment, a timeout is negotiated between client and server. The default minimum value of this timeout is 2 * tickTime, and max. is 20 * tickTime. So, with  all default server settings, you can get a session timeout anywhere between 4 to 40 seconds.

Comment: Depending upon which client library you are using, client can specify the session timeout (in ms), which it wants. If for eg. the negotiated timeout is 20 seconds, your ephemeral node will be deleted 20 seconds after client gets disconnected from server.

Comment: So, you want X in your question to be the negotiated session timeout.

Comment: We increased the tickTime and this fixed the problem. I suppose your solution should work too.

Comment: Ok. Just be careful about increasing the tick time though. Tick time is the zookeeper wide unit of time. Everything from zookeeper server heartbeats to client timeouts are governed by tick time. Since you have increased the tick time, one possible side effect is that zookeeper server heartbeats (between the servers in the cluster) will happen after a longer time. As a result, a dead server in the cluster will be recognized later, and if a leader election is required (in case dead server was master), will be delayed too.